# Exception percolation in linux/python

Tags: python, linux, exception

Let's say I have the following flow of execution:

```
       def method1:
          try:
            method2()
          except Exception as e:
            handle_exception()

        def method2:
          command = "<some linux command>"
          status = execute_command(command) 
          if status != 0:   
            log_exception()

        def execute_command(command):
            subprocess.popen(command, <other params>)

        method1()
```

command.py

```
with open(path, 'w') as f: #this raises IOError
        #do something
```

Will `handle_exception()` be called? My understanding is a traceback will be printed instead since the exception won't percolate to `method1`. And this is because `execute_command(..)` will spawn a different process that will have it's own call stack. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: From the code you have shown, yes, `handle_exception` would be called because `method2` raises an exception or, more explicitly, `execute_command` raises an exception that is not handled by `method2`, thus it goes up in the call stack.

Comment: Why don't you try running it an adding some `print()` statements to see what it does? I've found that this is a great way to learn things like this :-)

Comment: And watch out when you edit your posts, you just scrapped all the formatting I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: if you want the `except` block to run if you get a status code other then 0 then raise an error in `method2`:

```
  if (status != 0)   
    log_exception()
    raise RuntimeError("got non-0 exit code: %d"%status)
```

Long answer with examples: it is highly dependent on how you are executing the command, `os.system` only raises an error if you don't give it a `str`:

```
import os
... #def method1 and method2
execute_command = os.system
method1()
```

this would call `log_exception()` since `<some linux command>` isn't a valid command.  But no error is raised so `handle_exception()` wouldn't be used.  You could also use `subprocess.call`:

```
import subprocess
... #def method1 and method2
execute_command = subprocess.call
method1()
```

This way `subprocess.call` raises an error when it can't find an executable called `<some linux command>`, but with a valid executable and failing process:

```
import subprocess

... #def method1

def method2():
  command = ["python","-c","INVALID CODE !!"]
  status = subprocess.call(command)
  if(status !=0):
      print("got non-0 status:  %r"%status)

method1()
```

This way there was an error in the call and returned non-0 status but that doesn't raise any errors in python, if you want `method2` to raise a python error for a non-0 exit status this is easy to do:

```
  if (status != 0)   
    log_exception()
    raise RuntimeError("got non-0 exit code: %d"%status)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was interested in the last example where the code within the second process raised an exception. So I believe my understanding was correct to begin with

Comment: using [`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) _may_ work instead for python commands since it stays in same traceback stack but it is completely different then opening a subprocess.

Answer (score -1):

No, it won't and a traceback won't be printed. Actually nothing visible by a user will happen (provided you fix the obvious syntax errors).

Comment: This has already [been suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802263/exception-percolation-in-linux-python/35802498#comment59274201_35802263) and is not a very [suitable answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This wasn't meant to be a suggestion but an actual answer to a previous version of the question. I'm pretty sure it's at least accurate for the question as it was formulated at that time. I guess that doesn't make it suitable though.

Comment: you do not provide context or explanation; In what case would nothing visible by a user happen?  In the original version of the question there was no call to `method1` which would result in no output but it was fairly obvious that it was not copy-paste runnable code.  It also wouldn't give any output if `log_exception` and `handle_exception` didn't display information but it is implied that they do.  So in what case would nothing visible by a user happen?

Comment: from the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): `Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.`  I suppose if brevity is acceptable then your answer is fine for the site, but please expand on your answer as I honestly though you were being sarcastic about not calling `method1` when I first read it.